# buttons executing 3 times in wenzhixin bootstrap-table child row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-table

The code below includes all the details for building the expanded details (child row) of the table. (there are actually 2, only showing the 1 I am having problems with).

When I expand a row there are buttons that I use to execute various functions. These buttons, at least some, appear to be executing 3 times.

I noticed the problem when it was necessary to use a confirmation for certain user actions. I noticed I was getting the confirmation for the action 3 times. I Have been unable to find the cause.

The buttons are using a dynamic naming convention so each row gets a unique name. They are created when the row is expanded. The particular 2 in question are listed in the bullets for they can be located easier (I have not implemented the 3rd yet, but I'm confident if I can solve one of these it will lead me to fixing all of them);

- delext_
- renumber_

  ```
  function compExtInfo($detail, row) {
      pID = row.ID;

      $detail.append('<div id="exttoolbar2_'+pID+'">');
      $detail.append('<button id="addext_'+pID+'" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Row </button>');
      $detail.append('<button id="editext2_'+pID+'" class="btn btn-success"> Edit Row </button>');
      $detail.append('<button id="delext_'+pID+'" class="btn btn-info"> Delete Row </button>');
      $detail.append('<button id="renumber_'+pID+'" class="btn btn-warning"> Auto Renumber Days </button>');
      $detail.append('<button id="finalize_'+pID+'" class="btn btn-danger"> Finalize 90 Day Report </button>');
      $detail.append('</div>');
      buildTable2($detail.append('<table id="exttable2_'+pID+'"></table>').find('table'), pID);
  }
  function buildTable2($ext, ID) {
      $ext.bootstrapTable({
          url: 'get90dayinfo.php?ID='+ID+'&d='+$.now(),
          uniqueId: 'ID',
          clickToSelect: true,
          toolbar: '#exttoolbar_'+ID,
          columns: [
              ...
          ],
          onLoadSuccess: function(row, index){

              $('#addext_'+ID).click(function(){
                  $('#message').collapse('hide');
                  var gAPI = $.map($ext.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
                      $('#addID90').val(row.ID);
                      $('#addtable2').val('exttable2_'+row.ID);
                      //get the next day to populate
                      var gDay = $.get( 'get90maxday.php?ID='+ID+'&d='+$.now(), function(data) {
                           $('#addday').val(data);
                      });

                      $('#add90modal').modal();
                  });
                  return row.id;
              });
              $('#delext_'+ID).click(function(){
                  var pTmp = $.map($ext.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
                      $('#message').collapse('hide');
                      pID = row.ID;
                      pDay = row.day;
                      pDate = row.date;

                      if (confirm('This will delete day '+pDay+' date '+pDate)){
                          $.get( '90deldata.php?ID='+pID+'&day='+pDay+'&d='+$.now(), function( data ) {
                              if(data=='success'){
                                  $('#message p').text('Day '+pDay+' Date '+pDate+' successfully deleted');
                                  $('#message').collapse('show');
                                  $ext.bootstrapTable('refresh');
                                  $().abort;
                              }
                          }); 

                      }
                  });
              });
              $('#editext2_'+ID).click(function(){
                  $('#message').collapse('hide');
                  var gAPI = $.map($ext.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {

                      $('#editext90modal').modal();
                  });
                  return row.id;
              });
              $('#renumber_'+ID).click(function(){
                  $('#message').collapse('hide');
                  $ext.bootstrapTable('checkAll');
                  $('#renumber_'+ID).unbind('click');

                  var pID = $.map($('#90day').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
                      return row.ID;
                  });

                  $('#message').collapse('hide');
                  pID = row.ID;
                  var updatedWell = $.map($('#90day').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
                      return row.well_name+' '+row.well_num+' API '+row.api;
                  });

                  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to re-order '+updatedWell)){
                      $.get('90dayrenumber.php?ID='+pID+'&d='+$.now(), function(data) {
                          if(data=='success'){
                              $('#message p').text(updatedWell+' successfully re-ordered');
                              $('#message').collapse('show');
                              $ext.bootstrapTable('refresh');
                          }
                      }); 
                  }
              });
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: I guess that you're registering the `.click()` events multiple times (calling `buildTable2` method). Set them outside of any function that may run multiple times. If the buttons doesn't exist in the DOM initially, use event delegation - `.on()`

Comment: hmm...  I am going to have to explore 'how' to move it out. I changed to it t a .on() event. and that made no difference (did not think it would). 

I will have to play with the multiple click idea and see if I can use a static name kick off an event for the dynamic name with it moved out. I had code 'somewhere' for that. :)

Comment: I got the button to fire with a dynamic name handler `$('button[id^=renumber]').on('click', function(){` , and got it to fire just fine. Then I moved it out of the `onLoadSuccess: function(row, index){ ...}` area and into my script area, and it will not fire at all. It isn't finding it, or firing until it is called from the with the same 'dynamic' events. :(